# difference in app working between simulator and iphone/ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am building an iOS chatting app in Obj C. user can post messages. There are certain anomalies in the working of app on iphone/ipad. It works well on simulator.

1) on an iphone, when I post a message, though the pop up says messaged posted successfully, it doesn't show up on the message screen. When I delete a message, though the pop up says message deleted successfully, but it still appears in messages screen. This problem is not there in simulator.
2) on an ipad, when I try to add an image to a message, it crashes the app. but in ipad simulator, this problem doesn't exist.

there are no compilation warnings or errors. Simulator working is fine. but some features not working properly on the real device.

Any thought?

Comment: What's your code? What's your crash log when it crash?

Comment: have you checked both ios versions?

Comment: both ios version above 9